# Chrome DevTools. Save console output to file automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I try to get text content from the webpage. For example Google.com

I write at console:

```
$ ('#SIvCob').innerText
```

and get:

```
"Google offered in: русский"
```

This is the text, what I find out. Now I want to save it to file (.txt).

Two moments: there is no only one item, that I search, actually 7-10.  And, there is a refresh every second! I go to write a cycle.

I know about copy() function and about right click on the console and "Save As," but I need a CODE, which will do it automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147366/how-to-create-and-save-file-in-developer-tools-console-of-google-chrome-browser

Answer (score 0):

The browser has no API to write to the file system since that would be a security risk. But you can use [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org) and their [File System API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html) to write you text file.

You will also need to use the [HTTP API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html) to get the web content. And you will also need to parse your HTML, you can do it with [fast-html-parser](https://github.com/taoqf/node-html-parser) or any other module of your choice. (high5, htmlparser, htmlparser2, htmlparser2-dom, hubbub, libxmljs, ms/file, parse5, ...)

```
 var http = require('http');
 var fs = require('fs');
 var parser = require('node-html-parser');
 var options = {
   host: 'www.google.com',
   port: 80,
   path: '/index.html'
 };
 var file = '/path/to/myFile.txt';
 http.get(options, function(res) {
   res.setEncoding('utf8');
   var body = ''; 
   res.on('data', function (chunk) {body += chunk});
   res.on('end', function () { 
     var dom = parser.parse(body);
     var text = dom.querySelector('#SIvCob').text;
     fs.writeFile(file, text, function (err) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('The file has been saved!');
     });
   });
 });
```